# Delete expired posts in wordpress by date meta data custom field

Tags: date, custom-fields, wordpress

---Resolved: Code Works as shown---

I have this piece of code that I think should work, but alas...

If anyone could take a peek and see if there something obvious.  I have reviewed a lot of resources on the wordpress codex, but have tried all I can think of.

```
// expired_post_delete hook fires when the Cron is executed

add_action( 'expired_post_delete', 'delete_expired_posts' );

// This function will run once the 'expired_post_delete' is called

function delete_expired_posts() {

$todays_date = current_time('mysql');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date',
            'value' => $todays_date,
            'type' => 'DATE',
            'compare' => '<'
            )
    )
);
 $posts = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $posts->have_posts() ) {

    while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
        $posts->the_post();
        wp_delete_post(get_the_ID());
    }

} else {
// no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Add function to register event to WordPress init
add_action( 'init', 'register_daily_post_delete_event');

// Function which will register the event
function register_daily_post_delete_event() {
// Make sure this event hasn't been scheduled
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'expired_post_delete' ) ) {
    // Schedule the event
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'expired_post_delete' );
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `'value' => $todays_date` (without the quotes)?

Comment: Made that update, was still not producing, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_date()` needs to be used within the Loop. Outside the Loop, it will return null. Use [current_time()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) instead.

```
$todays_date = current_time('mysql'); // returns YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and still no results.  I need a way to see the values to debug, no idea where the code breaks down...it's a mess.  lol.  Thank you for the tip, nonetheless.  Do I need to truncate the time off the current_time()?  Or if I compare a date will know to ignore the time?  Thanks Again!

Comment: What's the format of the date stored in the post meta?

Comment: Date is stored as YYYY-MM-DD, copied from post: 2014-12-01

Comment: Becky Thank you for your help.  Your advice put me at ease about the date issue which was one lest thing to worry about.  Last bug was silly...did not properly create an instance of the WP_Query object.